# Unicode Decode PHP Return does not work

Tags: php, unicode

I am meeting one problam in PHP :

```
// Russian Language  ( in english it works)
$string = "Гиорги"   ;  
echo $un;  // result is Гиорги
return  $un; // Result is \u0413\u0438\u043e\u0440\u0433\u0438
```

I need return to be also decoded in RETURN and how I do that? I tried :

```
return json_decode('"'.$un.'"');
```

no works

I am returning Array  :

```
// here  $un  is "Гиорги";
    $img = 'resimg.php?r='. $Test['id'] .'&u='. $u .'&f='. $f.'&fn='. $fn.'&un='. $un ;
// I am only showing you $img so leave others I didnt pasted like $sd or so. so just leave it target $img only
         return array(
                          'status' => true,
                          'img' => $img, // this is 
                          'code' => str_replace('+', '@', $this->enCode($sd)),
                          'fname' => $Test['descripcion'],
                          'ResIF' => $Test['id']                  
                        );
                    }
```

and after this I get this result in console :

```
"status":true,"img":"resimg.php?r=248&u=295706407437389&f=295706407437389&fn=\u0413\u0438\u043e\u0440\u0433\u0438&un=\u0413\u0438\u043e\u0440\u0433\u0438","code":"4trQytfe4KOL197g0tjMp93R26TrqpufnZ\/ipp2erqSZoZmppJ2enKylopHLtp@ioJypo52bnK2goJ6dspPP2aJJADkjNTc@6TsYSSWP4NO2Pfw7HUkrOus1LD0hl4Xgp6GckZnhzt7Zs6Wal4Xu28rYyrM9\/DsdSSs66zUsPSGXhd\/bytjKsz38Ox1JKzrrNSw9IZeF69LctKmzn52j","fname":"ststst","ResIF":"248"}
```

So if I echo, it showing in console correct name,  but if return it shows encoded.

Comment: it is a normal behaviour, this is how utf8 works

Comment: Yes but then I am trying to paint this TEXT into Image with  imagestring();  so only English is showing, other language is not showing


$string = iconv("Windows-1250", "Latin2", $un);

Comment: if I am doing $string = $un  ;  $un from that code I pasted  from start;
So nothing is showing actually, 
if I do $string =  "тест"   (russian language) then it shows  other alpabetical numerals